# Is there a way to iterate over struct attributes?

Tags: cython

Sorry if this has been asked before. It does seem very simple. I am wondering if there is a way to iterate over struct attributes.

E.g.

```
ctypedef struct Foo:
    int a, b
    
cdef Foo foo = [1, 2]


#want something like this
for i in range(2):
    print(foo[i])
```

Comment: Make it a union with a `int[2]`, so you can either access by name or iterate the union-ed array?

Comment: Structs can be auto-converted to dicts so you could do that (but the iteration won't be hugely fast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @ShadowRanger's comment, the closest I can come up with how to do this is like so:

```
ctypedef struct Foo:
    int a, b
    
cdef union Bar:
    Foo *f
    int *g

cdef Foo foo = [1, 2]
cdef Bar bar

bar.f = &foo

for i in range(2):
    print(bar.g[i])
```

Wrapping the struct with a corresponding array. This would only work if the struct was a collection of all the same type, however.